# Web.Release.Config authentication attribute

Tags: c#, windows-authentication, web-release-config

I defined a WebApi which takes the credetianls from the browser, it works. 
After deploying it I have to edit the Authentication on the server from `Anonymouns` to `Windows`. I tried to add `<authentication mode="Windows"/>` to the Web.Config.Release but it doesn't change...
Why? Suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `.Release.Config` file is not a `.Config` file as such - it's a file that describes how to *transform* the default `Web.Config` file into a new `Web.Config` file for release.

So, you don't simply add nodes to it - you need to specify the modifications you want to make using the defined syntax for this - see https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx

In your case, you probably want something like:

```
...
<system.web>
    <authentication mode="Windows" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" />
</system.web>
...
```